# Каким из методов можно реализовать верстку?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Каким методом можно сверстать такое отображение блока с текстом и стрелкой внизу?

[image: картинка]

Comment: html css и всё ...если хотите поизврощаться то и ещё на svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  background-color: #e0efef;
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
}

.quote {
  background-color: #6b936a;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.name {
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

blockquote {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

blockquote::after {
  border-color: transparent #6b936a transparent transparent;
  border-image: none;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px;
  top: 40px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  right: 75%;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  border: 3px solid #9CC1D3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  position: relative;
  top: 1em;
  left: 30px;
}

.user-info {
  left: 50px;
  top: -100px;
  position: relative;
}

.person {
  font-size: 30px;
  left: 25px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="quote-box">
    <div class="quote">
      <blockquote>
        "The secret of getting ahead is getting started. The secret of getting started is breaking your complex overwhelming tasks into small manageable tasks, and starting on the first one."
      </blockquote>
    </div>

    <div class="name">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/06/12/05/people-2591869_960_720.jpg">
      <div class="user-info">
        <span class="person">Jeremy H.</span><br>
        <span>Manager</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```